# How to ask more than one multiple choice question?

Tags: bash

I would like to write a simple bash script for training multiple choice tests.  Ask one question; give four choices (a, b, c, d); if user enters input, show if it is wrong or right and continue with the next question.

Here is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo Question1="How much is 2+2?"
echo a="1"
echo b="2"
echo c="3"
echo d="4"
read Question1

if [ "$Question1" = "d" ];
then
    echo "this is correct"
else
    echo "this is NOT correct"
fi
```

All samples about the `read` command example I found so far on youtube etc. stop after one question. How can I ask multiple questions? Entering another question does not work and bash shows a syntax error:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

echo Question1="How much is 2+2?"
echo a="1"
echo b="2"
echo c="3"
echo d="4"
read Question1

if [ "$Question1" = "d" ];
then
    echo "this is correct"
else
    echo "this is NOT correct"

echo Question2="How much is 2+1?"
echo a="1"
echo b="2"
echo c="3"
echo d="4"
read Question2

if [ "$Question2" = "c" ];
then
    echo "this is correct"
else
    echo "this is NOT correct"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is giving you a syntax error because you don't have a `fi` after your first `if` statement, probably an error during copy/pasting.

Afterwards it should work fine.

Comment: Thx^^. Don't know, how I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

This is where [the `select` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-select) is handy

```bash
PS3="How much is 2+2? "
select choice in 1 2 3 4; do
    if [[ $choice == 4 ]]; then
        echo "Correct"
        break
    fi
    echo "Incorrect"
done

PS3="How much is 2+1? "
select choice in 1 2 3 4; do
    if [[ $choice == 3 ]]; then
        echo "Correct"
        break
    fi
    echo "Incorrect"
done
```

Or, we can encapsulate the repetition in a function:

```bash
question() {
    local PS3="$1 " answer=$2 choice
    shift 2
    select choice in "$@"; do
        if [[ $choice == "$answer" ]]; then
            echo "Correct"
            break
        fi
        echo "Incorrect"
    done
}

question "How much is 2+2?" 4 1 2 3 4
question "How much is 2+1?" 3 1 2 3 4
```